# error returned when no error thrown..WEB API C#

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api

I have a Web API 2.0 action that does the following:

```
  [System.Web.Http.Route("api/wdretrievedata")]
    [System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult RetrieveUserData(string email)
    {
        var user = new WDUserData();
        user.FirstName = "FirstName";
        user.LastName="LastName";
        user.PhoneNumber="PhoneNumber";
        return Ok(user);

    }
```

AS you can see, no errors are here. I run this in Postman and get results (omitted certain data for security):

[image]

I run this in my code via $.ajax like so:

```
 $.ajax({
                url: 'http://localhost:49352/api/wdretrievedata?email=myemail@gmail.com',
                type: "GET",
                async: true,

                success: function (data) {
                   //never goes here
                },
                error: function (err) {
                     //always goes here
                    //err.statusText says 'error' and nothing else
                        alert(err.statusText);
                }
            });
```

The API call always returns in the error section and contains no data whatsoever. How do I get my API call to work via the $.ajax call like Postman? Thanks

If this helps, i've deployed my api to my web server. Troy this url to see what i'm getting:

http://tce-windows-env.hiujwmcthx.us-east-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/api/wdretrievedata?email=troy.compton@gmail.com

Comment: Can you show us the error? Aren't you getting errors due the fact that you're calling to the same origin (localhost)?

Comment: what is the response status code of the call

Comment: the response status code is 200

Comment: try to add breakpoint to your action and check if ajax reaches it

Comment: the call is being made. the action is reached when the ajax call is made. Im stumped

Comment: `error: function err) {` you have missed  to close brackets

Comment: in my actual code, the brackets are fine. i copied and pasted this and edited out all unnecessary code

Comment: i've added a url to test with

Comment: getting error : `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

Comment: did you run this in postman or fiddler?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154158/discussion-between-demo-and-boundforglory).

Comment: @demo - when you showed me the error you received, i found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource and this is the answer...how do i give you credit? you helped me find this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research with @BoundForGlory, it was detected that problem with  Cross-Origin Requests.

One of options is to add custom header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` to allow CORS

```
<httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
    </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
[System.Web.Http.Route("api/wdretrievedata")]
[System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> RetrieveUserData(string email)
{
    var user =  await new WDUserData();
    user.FirstName = "FirstName";
    user.LastName="LastName";
    user.PhoneNumber="PhoneNumber";
    return Ok(user);

}
```

Comment: this doesnt compile

Comment: @BoundForGlory, you need to add `using system.threading.tasks` if I'm not wrong

Comment: i did that and even added return Task.FromResult(user). Still the same problem

Comment: i added the url so you can test this.